# Checking for whitespace after each word

Tags: java, character

I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell if there's whitespace in this program. The program is supposed to take a string, change it to char data, and then capitalize the first letter of every word.

The code is the following:

```
   import java.util.*;
public class wrapper1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        System.out.println("Enter a phrase: ");
        s1=input.nextLine();
        s1=s1.trim();
        int counter;
        char c;
        boolean flag=true;

        for(counter=0; counter < s1.length(); counter++)
        {
            c=s1.charAt(counter);
            while(counter < s1.length())
            {
                if(flag==true)
                {
                    Character.toUpperCase(c);
                    flag=false;
                }
                else if(!Character.isLetter(c))
                {
                    flag=true;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

I made a loop and the goal of that loop is to go through the data capitalizing the first letter of every word by setting the flag to false, and then back to true whenever it finds a whitespace.

However, I do not know how to write the else if statement to check for whitespace, therefore that is what I'm looking for (a way to write that statement).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post compilable code please? Also the javadoc of `toUpperCase` states _"**Returns** the uppercase equivalent of the character, if any; otherwise, the character itself."_

Comment: I don't have compilable code as I don't know how to write out the last part of the if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct your code remove the while statement and assign the result of toUpperCase to c as mentioned by ZouZou

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1;
    System.out.println("Enter a phrase: ");
    s1=input.nextLine();
    s1=s1.trim();
    int counter;
    char c;
    boolean flag=true;

    for(counter=0; counter < s1.length(); counter++)
    {
        c=s1.charAt(counter);
        if(flag==true)
        {
            c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            flag=false;
        }
        else if(s1.charAt(counter)==' ')
        {
            flag=true;
        }
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Note that your solution only treats spaces as separator characters not other whitespaces (such as tabs) or a sequence of whitespace characters.

Here is a more concise solution that treats tabs and sequences

```
for(String s : s1.split("\\s+")){
    System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1) + " ");
}
```

And an even more concise version would be to use Apache Commons [WordUtils.capitalize](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thank you I had actually tried the s1.charAt(counter)=' ') and it hadn't worked before, but it was because I had                              c = Character.toUpperCase(c); written out wrong.

Comment: I can't use material I haven't dealt with yet but I will look into that for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned by srm you could also replace the second instance of s1.charAt(counter) with c

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use "charAt" (your code is invalid there, afaikt). You already have the current char at hand. So check if it is a whitespace. You only have to consider consecutive whitespaces - something like `if(flag==true && c != ' ')`

Additionally, why do it that way? Why not use String.split(...) ?

P.S. Convention says we use Class-names starting upper-case.

Comment: We haven't dealt with the String.split method, and we're limited to use things that have been discussed in the online lectures.

Comment: Or even better if(flag==true && !Character.isWhitespace(c))